# what is the name or term for // in front of resources?

Tags: url, uri

So http://cdnjs.com/ and some of my peers are recommending that we use `//` in front of the resource. What is this term or technology called? As I understand the purpose is so that `http` or `https` is preserved. However when I want to google say `yepnope`'s compatibility with it, what do I call it?

Comment: Protocol Relative URL

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a "relative URL" — in this case, a URL with no protocol part (and so it uses the protocol from its parent document), just like `/foo.html` is a relative URL with no protocol or servername parts (and so uses the protocol and server of its parent document).

The purpose of protocol-relative URLs is that they are portable between `http` and `https` documents (and a teensy bit shorter). So if you have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/etc.css">
```

...on the page `http://example.com`, the URL expands to

```
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/etc.css
```

...but if it's on the page `https://example.com`, it expands to

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/etc.css
```

...and you don't get the "mixed secure and insecure content" warning from the browser.

One slight downside is if you're doing some quick-and-dirty local testing using files you've opened directly from the file system, their protocol is `file:`, and so the URL ends up being

```
file://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/etc.css
```

...which probably doesn't refer to a valid resource on your computer (and leads to questions on SO).

More on my blog: [*Skipping the protocol*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/skipping-protocol.html)

Comment: so sounds like the term for specifically what I was mentioning is `protocol relative url` ?

Comment: @Maslow: If you want to be that specific, probably, yeah. We don't usually get that specific with other kinds of relative URLs ("server relative URL", "path relative URL", etc.), we just call them "relative URLs". But yes, basically. :-)